# How to hide "Title" standard column in custom list using visual studio

Tags: content-type, sharepoint-server, custom-list, site-column, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on custom lists of sharepoint 2013.

I created many lists in each one I want to hide the standard column "Title" from visual studio . I know how to deal with this in SharePoint Site ( by making this field hidden in the column list ) , but every time I make changes in my list ( in visual studio) and deploy the project , the Title field becomes required.

Is there a way to force the "Title" standard column to "hidden" in visual studio ?

can anyone help me Please?

Answer (score 1):

a coded solution.

what your talking about is the field that you want hidden!

```
SPField.Hidden()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.hidden.aspx

and to get the field use:

```
Fields.GetFieldByInternalName()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldcollection.getfieldbyinternalname(v=office.14).aspx

the title field becomes required and is a standard field part of any template list, so the first step through code would be to make it a none required field and then set it to hidden!

```
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(http://thesiteurl:1234))
    {
       using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
       {
          SPList list = web.Lists["listName"];

          SPField spfield = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title");

          spfield.Required = false;

          spfield.Hidden = true;

          spfield.Update();
       }
    }
```

Comment: I get the solution , it is just by making the standard field "Title" hidden using SharePoint designer

Comment: you want to do it in sharepoint desinger? thought you wanted to do it in visual studios?

Answer (score 0):

When adding **field** elements to the list, or adding **fieldref** elements to a content type, you can add the following attributes to hide the column:

ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE" | "FALSE"

ShowInEditForm="TRUE" | "FALSE"

ShowInListSettings="TRUE" | "FALSE"

ShowInNewForm="TRUE" | "FALSE"

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543225(v=office.15).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms437580(v=office.15).aspx